# Store logged in user knockout

Tags: javascript, authentication, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a web application in ASP.net MVC 5 and using knockout.js. I want to implement the user authentication i.e. Login/Logout facility. I have few question is this regard:

1. Where and how I should store information of logged in user while application is running? Is it good to store the logged in user information as Session variable?
2. If I store logged in user information in Session variable, will I be able to provide knockout binding with session variable?
3. I want to enable/disable the controls (even in _Layout.cshtml as well) in my view based on whether user is logged in or not. So how I can achieve this requirement.

Comment: yes you can do everything . Try extracting `session` variable data and keep the content in observable & bind it . Good Luck !

Comment: @supercool if I have to extract session variable and store it as observable then I will have to do it in each page view model separately right? Is there any alternative to this like some kind of global observable variable?

Comment: you can do globally in layout store it in a variable and access variable in your viewModels observables . hope that helps